# Trying to use multiple arguments for .append, anyway how?

Tags: python, list, append

I am trying to append a set of objects combined into one as a single object on the end of a list. Is there any way I could achieve this?

I've tried using multiple arguments for .append and tried searching for other functions but I haven't found any so far.

```
yourCards = []
cards =["Ace","Two","Three","Four","Five","Six","Seven","Eight","Nine","Ten","Jack","Queen","King"]
suits = ["Hearts","Diamonds","Clubs","Spades"]

yourCards.append(cards[random.randint(0,12)],"of",suits[random.randint(0,3)])
```

I expected the list to have a new element simply as "Two of Hearts" etc. but instead I recieve this error:

```
TypeError: append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)
```

Comment: You supplied three arguments to `append`, but `append` only accepts one argument.  Notice the commas in your argument list?

Comment: Do you mean you're trying to build the string `"Two of Hearts"`? How would passing separate arguments achieve that? Do that *before* you pass it to append. Also note the existence of `random.choice`, and that there's nothing to stop you having multiple copies of the same card.

Comment: You can use `extend` instead: `yourCards.append((cards[random.randint(0,12)],"of",suits[random.randint(0,3)]))`.

Comment: @a_guest I think they want to add a single value that combines the three parts.

Comment: Maybe you got this idea from the `print` function? It joins arguments you pass to it with spaces, but that’s not how function calls work in general; that’s just a convenience for printing. When you have two string objects, you can concatenate them with the `+` operator: `x + " of " + y`.

Comment: why not just add them with a `+`? like `yourCards.append(cards[random.randint(0,12)]+'of'+suits[random.randint(0,3)])`?

Comment: How would I concate strings (sorry I'm new)

Comment: Just like the comments above describe. Add them with + signs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are sending `append()` multiple arguments not a string. Format the argument as a string as such. Also, `random.choice()` is a better approach than `random.randint()` here as stated by: @JaSON below.

**3.6+ using `f-strings`**

```
yourCards.append(f"{random.choice(cards)} of {random.choice(suites)}")
```

**Using `.format()`**

```
yourCards.append("{} of {}".format(random.choice(cards), random.choice(suites)))
```

**string concatenation**

```
yourCards.append(str(random.choice(cards)) + " of " + str(random.choice(suites)))
#You likely don't need the str() but it's just a precaution
```

**Improving on Alex's `join()` approch**

```
' of '.join([random.choice(cards), random.choice(suites)])
```

Comment: IMHO it would be better to use `random.choice(cards)` and `random.choice(suites)`

Comment: @JaSON edited. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
yourCards.append(' '.join([random.choice(cards), "of", random.choice(suits)]))
```

Comment: I like this one too. but could be improved using `' of '.join([cards[random.randint(0, 12)], suits[random.randint(0, 3)]])`

Comment: Thanks! I like keeping the "of" in order so the code also forms a sentence.